# Error on "vssadmin list shadows"

Tags: windows-7, windows, volume-shadow-copy, vss

Using an admin cmd prompt, I typed: `vssadmin list shadows`, and got the following:

> Contents of shadow copy set ID: {...}
>
> Contained 1 shadow copies at creation time: ...
>
> **Error: The shadow copy provider had an unexpected error while trying
>   to process the specified command.**

I then tried this on another computer and received the same error. Both are Windows 7 x64 's.

Is there some step missing here?

**EDIT**

I now tried "list volumes" and got the same error message. (Just from "Error" onwards.)

**UPDATE**

Running PowerShell as admin and executing `Get-ComputerRestorePoint` *does* work. But still no luck with `vssadmin` even though I disabled system restore, deleted all restore points, reenabled, and created a restore point. And as mentioned - PowerShell does find it. (And also as mentioned - This is on two computers.)

Comment: Does it actually say "{...}", or does it give a GUID in there? What have you tried already? IE: Have you tried axing all existing shadow copies and creating a (single) new one?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It gives a real GUID. (And a real date for the other ellipsis.) Deleting all of the shadow copies sounds like a good idea, but I wouldn't want to lose those restore points. As far as I understand - they rely on this. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Yup, but if they're corrupted, there of no use to you anyway. Better to axe them and make a clean one you know works now, instead of discovering/remembering they're corrupt later on when you really need them. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I just now tried "list volumes" and got the same error (edited into question).

Comment: Bizarre. I wish I had an answer for you. Seems like corruption, jus tfinidng it will be tricky. :) All I can think of off hand to try next is run a `chkdsk` to ensure there's no file-system/disk error, and a `SFC /scannow` to ensure some system file isn't corrupted someplace.  I'd say do those, edit the results into your answer, and hopefully something will click for someone. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Update: chkdsk found no problems. I ran it on only one of the computers. Since this happens on both computers (including the "list volumes" error) - this is quite strange. I haven't used `sfc` yet. Thanks again.